# How to identify a generator vs list comprehension

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I have this:

```
>>> sum( i*i for i in xrange(5))
```

My question is, in this case **am I passing a list comprehension or a generator object** to sum ? How do I tell that? Is there a general rule around this?

Also remember **sum by itself needs a pair of parentheses to surround its arguments. I'd think that the parentheses above are for sum and not for creating a generator object.** Wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are passing in a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

A [list comprehension is specified with square brackets](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) (`[...]`). A list comprehension builds a *list object* first, so it uses syntax closely related to the list literal syntax:

```
list_literal = [1, 2, 3]
list_comprehension = [i for i in range(4) if i > 0]
```

A generator expression, on the other hand, creates an iterator object. Only when iterating *over* that object is the contained loop executed and are items produced. The generator expression does not *retain* those items; there is no list object being built.

A generator expression always uses `(...)` round parethesis, but when used as the *only* argument to a call, the parenthesis can be omitted; the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
sum((i*i for i in xrange(5)))  # with parenthesis
sum(i*i for i in xrange(5))    # without parenthesis around the generator
```

Quoting from the generator expression documentation:

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument. See section [*Calls*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) for the detail.

Comment: @Martin Pieters But remember sum by itself needs a pair of parentheses to surround its arguments. I'd think that the parentheses above are for sum and not for creating a generator object. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @abc: I was just addressing that; the parenthesis around the generator are *optional* in that case.

Comment: @Martin Pieters Great, I see your update now. That was the actual burning question I had. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions are enclosed in `[]`:

```
>>> [i*i for i in xrange(5)]  # list comprehension
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> (i*i for i in xrange(5))  # generator
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x2cee40>
```

You are passing a generator.

Answer (score 2):

That is a generator:

```
>>> (i*i for i in xrange(5))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01A27A08>
>>>
```

List comprehensions are enclosed in `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be asking, "does this syntax truly cause `sum` to consume a generator one item at a time, or does it secretly create a `list` of every item in the generator first"? One way to check this is to try it on a very large range and watch memory usage:

```
sum(i for i in xrange(int(1e8)))
```

Memory usage for this case is constant, where as `range(int(1e8))` creates the full list and consumes several hundred MB of RAM.

You can test that the parentheses are optional:

```
def print_it(obj):
    print obj

print_it(i for i in xrange(5))
# prints <generator object <genexpr> at 0x03853C60>
```

Comment: Very useful information on checking ram usage to detect list comprehension or generator expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

    class myclass:

            def __init__(self,arg):
                    self.p = arg
                    print type(self.p)
                    print self.p





    if __name__ == '__main__':

            c = myclass(i*i for i in xrange(5))
```

And this prints:

```
$ ./genexprorlistcomp.py 
<type 'generator'>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5344c7cf00>
```

Which is consistent with what Martin and mdscruggs explained in their post.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a generator object, list comprehension is surrounded by `[]`.

Comment: But remember sum by itself needs a pair of parentheses to surround its arguments. I'd think that the parentheses above are for `sum` and not for creating a generator object. Wouldn't you agree?